# How to align a multiline prop?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

In eslintrc I have :

```
"react/jsx-indent": ["warn", 4],
"react/jsx-indent-props": ["warn", 4]
...
```

this produces code like this

```
    <div
        className={cn(
 spacingCSS["marginBottom_xl"],
 spacingCSS["marginTop_l"],
 "form__how-to"
 )}
    >
```

I would like it to look like this

```
    <div
        className={cn(
        spacingCSS["marginBottom_xl"],
        spacingCSS["marginTop_l"],
        "form__how-to"
        )}
    >
```

Comment: ESLint doesn't produce any code, it's a static analyser that warns you if code violates a rule. Are you using a formatter like [prettier](https://prettier.io/)? Which IDE are you using?

Comment: By "produce" I meant it formats the code like so (applies indent to the tag and prop name, but not to the prop's body). Im using VScode and no prettier.

Comment: ESlint doesn't format code either, you'll need to look at the available options in VSCode for code formatting, or alternatively add your own formatter plugin that'll give you more control over it.